# .NET CF Forms - Me.Font - Disposing Controls Default Font

Tags: vb.net, winforms, compact-framework

I've been trying to identify a memory leak with a custom control when I've noticed something odd:

```
Private f = Me.Font

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
     If f IsNot Me.Font Then 'ALWAYS TRUE
         f.Dispose()
         f = Me.Font
     End If
     ...
End Sub
```

Me.Font returns a different instance each time which has lead me to question other cases where I have called Me.Font.

Normally this isn't a big deal but paint can be called up to every 500ms in this control.

Is Me.Font generated each time it is called an therefore should be disposed each time? Are there any other control properties like this i need to be wary of?

Comment: If the `Me.Font` is created by the form/User Control, then that form/UC should be disposing if it.  Its not clear why you would want to do so in a Paint event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a control inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and you haven't changed the *current font* nor the *default font* of it, this seems pretty logical.

---

If we take a look at [**Microsoft's Reference Source**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for the .NET Framework we can see that the [**`Control.Font` property**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9df809cb5bb5d985) initially tries to get the current font of the control:

```cs
Font font = (Font)Properties.GetObject(PropFont);
if (font != null) {
    return font;
}
```

If there is no current font (if its `null`, or `Nothing` in Visual Basic) it tries to get its parent's font instead:

```cs
Font f = GetParentFont();
if (f != null) {
    return f;
}
```

Now, `GetParentFont()` will return `null` if the control has no parent (this could go all the way back until it gets to the parent form). If this gets to the last parent `GetParentFont()` will return `null`, thus making the execution continue. Since the control is not an ActiveX control the `if (IsActiveX)` check will fail and move on to:

```cs
AmbientProperties ambient = AmbientPropertiesService;
if (ambient != null && ambient.Font != null) {
    return ambient.Font;
}
```

I am not sure what this does but if even that check fails we're getting to the interesting part:

```cs
return DefaultFont;
```

---

The control returns the `DefaultFont` property, and if we [**go to its code**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,68e74c04f860bdbf):

```cs
if (defaultFont == null) {
    defaultFont = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
    Debug.Assert(defaultFont != null, "defaultFont wasn't set!");
}

return defaultFont;
```

we can see that it checks if the control already has defined its own default font, and if it **hasn't** it will return the default font for all standard controls (via `SystemFonts.DefaultFont`).

If we finally jump to [**the code for `SystemFonts.DefaultFont`**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/SystemFonts.cs,4ecb5727867024c1) we can see that it will create a variable called `defaultFont`, which it will return in the end.

```cs
Font defaultFont = null;
```

Now when looking on how the variable is assigned, we can see that it always creates a new `Font` instance (which would be what causes your issue):

```cs
//Each line represents an example taken from the code.
defaultFont = new Font("MS UI Gothic", 9);
defaultFont = new Font("Tahoma", 8); //This appears two times.
defaultFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8);
defaultFont = FontInPoints(defaultFont);

//FontInPoints only have one line: "return new Font(...);"
```

---

So we can now draw the conclusion that every time you call `YourControl.Font` it will return a new `Font` instance ***if you haven't*** assigned a custom font/custom default font, and ***if all other checks fail*** making it get the Windows' default font.

Comment: So would assinging the controls font to itself solve prevent this being created every time it is called (i.e. Me.Font = Me.Font / this.Font = this.Font;)?

Comment: @apc : Maybe it would, because then it would set its internal `font` variable. However I am not sure about it. I haven't inspected all the code because it is somewhat hard to understand, so I don't know if it clones the custom font too. But if my answer's correct then the simplest thing you can do should be to just change the `Font` property of your control (like you said) and you should no longer have the problem.

Comment: @apc : So as you've marked this as the accepted answer, I take it as it worked like we thought it would do?

Comment: After some additional investigation it would seem that calling the Font property always returns a new instance. Even after setting Me.Font comparing (Me.Font is Me.Font) returns false. (the 'is' comparer works when comparing locally created fonts).

Comment: @apc : For a custom control you could always declare your own `Font` property. If it inherits another control with a `Font` property, just declare your property `Overrides` or `Shadows`